# Переход с PhpExcel на PhpSpreadsheet. Всего 70 строк, а перевести не выходит

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

Вот код.
В "штрих звездочка" находятся старые изменяемые кусочки кода, который прекрасно работает по библиотеке PhpExcel.
Пыталась переделать под PhpSpreadsheet, не работает, в чем может быть ошибка?

```
<?php
$titletxt = $_REQUEST['titletxt'];
$filename =$titletxt.'.txt';
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$csv = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
unlink($filename);
 
/*
require_once '../../resources/PHPExcel_1.7.9/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once '../../resources/PHPExcel_1.7.9/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php';
*/

use phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Settings;
use phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xls;
use phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType;
use phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\{Font, Border, Borders, Alignment, Fill, NumberFormat, Style};
require_once '../../resources/PhpSpreadsheet_1.16/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once ' ../../resources/PhpSpreadsheet_1.16/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xls.php';
///////////////////////////////////////////////

$title =  $_REQUEST['title'];
$title=preg_replace('/^(.*)[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9]$/iu','$1',$title);                                           
$title=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9]+/iu','$1_$2',$title);


$title = preg_replace('/[\s]+/','_',$title);
$title = preg_replace('/^[\w]*[\d]*[-]/','',$title);
$cN =  $_REQUEST['cN'];
$fn=$title.'_'.date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').'.xls';

/*
$validLocale = PHPExcel_Settings::setLocale('ru');
$excel = new PHPExcel();
$sheet=$excel->getActiveSheet();
$excelWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($excel);
*/

$validLocale = Settings::setLocale('ru');
$excel = new Spreadsheet(); //создаем экземпляр класса
$sheet = $excel->getActiveSheet(); // получаем текущий активный лист
$excelWriter = new Xls($excel);
////////////////////////////////

//$sheet->setTitle(mb_substr($title,0,20));
$sheet->setTitle("Лист1"); //устанавливаем текущему листу тайтл
//данные
$i=1;
foreach(explode("\n", $csv) as $row) //разбивает строку на подстроки
{   
   
    $j=0;// $i=0;    
    foreach(explode(";", $row) as $value)
    {   
        $chri=65+$j;
        $cellcode=chr($chri).$i;
        if (!empty($value) && preg_match("^[\d]+$", $value)){
            $temp=preg_replace('/[,]/','.',$value);
            $value=preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/','',$temp);   
            /*         
            $sheet->setCellValueExplicit($cellcode,$value,PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC);
            */
            $sheet->setCellValueExplicit($cellcode,$value,DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC); //запись в ячейку
            ///////////////////////////////////
        }
        else if (!empty($value) && preg_match("/^NaN$/", $value) != 1){
            $sheet->setCellValue($cellcode,$value);//запись в ячейку
        }       
        $j++;
    }    
    $i++;
}

/*
for($i = 0; $i < $j - 1; $i++){
    $sheet->getColumnDimension(PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($i))->setAutoSize(true);
}*/
for($i = 1; $i < $j - 1; $i++){ //в этой библиотеке нумерация колонок предполагается с 1
    $sheet->getColumnDimension(Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($i))->setAutoSize(true);//устанавливаем ширину столбцов
}
///////////////////////////////


//оформление
$hC=$sheet->getHighestColumn();
$hR=$sheet->getHighestRow();
/*
$sheet->getStyle('A1:' . $hC . $hR)->getBorders()->getAllBorders()->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN);
$sheet->getStyle('A1:' . $hC . $hR)->getFont()->setName('Arial Cyr');
$sheet->getStyle('A1:' . $hC . $hR)->getFont()->setSize(10);
$sheet->getStyle('A1:' . $hC . '1')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID);
$sheet->getStyle('A1:' . $hC . '1')->getFill()->getStartColor()->setRGB('d0fbfa');
$sheet->getStyle('A1:' . $hC . '1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
$sheet->getStyle('D2:' . $hC . $hR)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);
$sheet->getStyle('D2:'.$hC . $hR)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER_COMMA_SEPARATED1);
*/

$sheet->getStyle('A1:' . $hC . $hR)->getBorders()->getAllBorders()->setBorderStyle(Border::BORDER_THIN);///назначаем стиль области ячеек от A1 до нужного кол-ва
$sheet->getStyle('A1:' . $hC . $hR)->getFont()->setName('Arial Cyr');//имя шрифта
$sheet->getStyle('A1:' . $hC . $hR)->getFont()->setSize(10);//размер шрифта
$sheet->getStyle('A1:' . $hC . '1')->getFill()->setFillType(Fill::FILL_SOLID);
$sheet->getStyle('A1:' . $hC . '1')->getFill()->getStartColor()->setARGB('d0fbfa');///заливка ячеек
$sheet->getStyle('A1:' . $hC . '1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
$sheet->getStyle('D2:' . $hC . $hR)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);///
$sheet->getStyle('D2:'.$hC . $hR)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER_COMMA_SEPARATED1);///


////////////////////////////
//вывод
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$fn);
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");  
//$excelWriter = io_factory::createWriter($excel, 'Xlsx');      
$excelWriter->save('php://output');
```

P.S. Обязательно ли устанавливать библиотеку посредством Composer? В данном случае, она просто была скачана и помещена на сайт (расположение файлов видно в use)

Comment: А какие ошибки выдает? Библиотеку можно как угодно установить, лишь бы было подключение классов и namespace

Comment: Использование composer просто удобнее и у него есть встроенный loader для классов.

Comment: Работаю в VS Code, расширение Php intelephense показывает ошибки в местах обращения к Settings, Xlsx, Alignment, NumberFormat и др. и в строке $excel = new Spreadsheet(); Пишет undefined type

Comment: Как будто не подключили файлы компонентов

Comment: Не подскажите как это сделать или проверить?

Comment: require файлов, хотя там у вас loader подключен... Странно вообще

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо!
Код оказался рабочим. Ошибка в невнимательности: кодила под Php5 (упс).