# Php. Вопрос по указанию путей

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Ситуация:
1 файл лежит по пути: `\\10.41.220.5\www\resources\PhpSpreadsheet_1.16\simple.php` и в нем подключаются файлы библиотеки (скрин1)
2 файл лежит по пути: `\\10.41.220.5\www\bts_without_traffic_vvdutova\php\export_chart_xls.php` и в нем не удается сделать тоже самое (скрин2, расширение на VSCode "php intelephense" выдает ошибку). Что не так?

Я новичок. Помогите, пожалуйста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: при чем здесь  "VSCode  intelephense"? код выполняется на сервере а не в редакторе. На сервере код запускается? Ошибки выдаёт? **Какие?**

Comment: На сервере код не работает.  (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1254776/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81-phpexcel-%d0%bd%d0%b0-phpspreadsheet-%d0%92%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-70-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82?noredirect=1#comment2204909_1254776)
Как ошибки посмотреть не знаю. Через ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); не выходит.

Comment: Это шутка? Я же написал, даже жирным текстом выделил - **какие ошибки выдаёт на сервере**, если не работает. Ну невозможно узнать почему код не работает без сообщения об ошибке. Неужели непонятно, что без сообщения об ошибке бессмысленно гадать о причинах? Что ошибка - это единственный источник информации о проблеме?

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы! И я буду безмерно благодарна, если научите, где и как их надо смотреть! Видите ли, я совсем зеленая, только после универа, опыта нет, и так получилось, что и подсказать толком никто не может, поэтому и лажу по форумам в надежде((

Comment: Откуда информация что код "не работает"? Он должен что-то вообще делать? В чем конкретно проявляется это "не работает"? В нем точно есть ошибки? Если специально ошибку добавить, например указать несуществующий файл, ошибку выводит? До места с ошибкой исполнение вообще доходит?

Comment: В сообщении выше я прикрепила ссылку с чего все началось. 
Проблема сейчас такая. На сайте по нажатии кнопки должен формироваться файл Excel и идти на скачивание. Формирование было с использованием библиотеки PhpExcel, она устарела, надо переписать под поддерживаемый аналог PhpSpreadsheet. Переписала, вроде все по примерам из документации.
НО ПО НАЖАТИИ КНОПКИ выскакивает "Сейчас эта страница не работает".

Comment: Видимо, вы путаете то что нужно коду, и то, о чём знает VSCode. В общем и целом лучше не идти по тому пути что вы выбрали, а создать проект с composer.json файлом, поместить туда зависимость PhpSpreadsheet, установить её, и спокойно работать дальше, сделав require('vendor/autoload.php') в коде. И забыть про включение сторонних библиотек по относительным путям как страшный сон :)

Comment: Вся эта история не имеет отношения к вопросу. Надо получить сообщение об ошибке. Без этого вообще невозможно заниматься разработкой. Надо **сначала** разобраться как получать сообщения об ошибках, а потом уже писать первую строчку кода. Иначе это будет вот такое блуждание в темноте. И нет, любые надписи в редакторе не имеют отношения к ошибкам, происходящим на сервере. Если сервер локальный, то настроить вывод на экран, в настройках РНР. Если сервер боевой, то смотреть в логах

Comment: Плюс писать не сразу стену кода и потом гадать в каком кирпиче ошибка, а писать постепенно. Написал подключение библиотеки - проверил, работает ли. Написал еще какой-то кусок кода- проверил, работает ли. тогда и вопросы будет более осмысленные, не "вот код, он не работает" а "инклюд не работает" или "создание класса не работает". Надо добавлять отладочный вывод, на каждой строчке. после инклюдов - "подключились". после создания объекта "создали объект" и так далее.